# ASP.NET session is new for each request unless you write down something

Tags: asp.net, session

I need unique session id but each it's new unless you write something in it.
The fix looks like this `Session["stubkey"] = "fsdufhusd"` in page load method.
It's pretty odd to me. Is there any way to init session or probably I do something wrong with configs?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`SessionID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx) documentation recommends the same work-around you're using:

> When using cookie-based session state,
>   ASP.NET does not allocate storage for
>   session data until the Session  object
>   is used. As a result, a new session ID
>   is generated for each page request
>   until the session object is accessed.
>   If your application requires a static
>   session ID for the entire session, you
>   can either implement the Session_Start
>   method in the application's
>   Global.asax file and store data in the
>   Session object to fix the session ID,
>   or you can use code in another part of
>   your application to explicitly store
>   data in the Session object.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to initialize the session on page_load. You can initialize the session on Global.asax like this

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Session["init"] = 0;
}
```